# Uncaught Error: Packager is not running at http://192.168.0.100.19001

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I ran an app in a normal way in React-Native (EXPO):

- expo init Myproject
- cd Myproject
- start of wire

However, next to running the app, the following message appears:

_ Something went wrong. (I.e.
_ ** The marshaler is not running at http: //192.168.100.19001**_

What do I do?

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Hi! in fact, I had not even started the project but I went to emulate to test if everything was ok. Then there was this problem ...

Answer (score 8):

I found that this error message could arise for a very simple reason, make sure your smartphone running Expo is connected to the same subnetwork as your computer on which your dev server is running.

Answer (score 6):

After 5 hours of serious debugging, this article helped me. [Packager is not running at expo.](https://medium.com/@csiandal/packager-is-not-running-at-expo-c60351387e04)

> Restart all the devices.

That includes:
Your computer,
phone,
router.

Comment: I have included the answer. "Restart all the devices." is the summary of the answer provided in the link.

Answer (score 5):

To resolve this issue of Packager is not running at http://192.168.0.100.19001 ensure the computer and phone are on the same network.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue and tried so many refresh and resstart. and I observed my pc had switched networks and was on a different network. Switching to be on the same network as my phone resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

the problem may occur due to the firewall . try to close any firewall , any antivirus

Answer (score 1):

For windows 10:
Add inbound rules in your firewall

Answer (score 1):

first check whether your laptop and emulator or real device are on the same network ...in my case this was this was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have also had this issue for a while. I found out that i didn't switch back from LAN to LOCAL in the devTools Menu[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Expo app and I solved it by disabling the firewall for the 19001 port of my IP addres.

I use Ubuntu so I'm going to explain the step by step for doing it in that OS. Making it work in Windows and macOS should be easy as well but maybe somebody else could explain this better than me.

First you need to know your IPv4, just type in the terminal `ip a` and then search for the word *inet* and copy the sequence of numbers next to it. That is your IPv4.

After that, enter the command `sudo ufw allow from <your-IPv4> to any port <the-port>`, for example: `sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.100/24 to any port 19001`. This will add a rule to the firewall configuration and should fix the issue.

Obviously, use it at your own risk and remember to delete the previously created rule when you finish working with Expo with the command `sudo ufw delete allow from 192.168.0.100/24 to any port 19001`, just for security reasons. To check all the configured rules and the status of the firewall: `sudo ufw status`.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn the emulator's wifi on and if it's on airplane mode turn it off.

I had the same issue and now it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few things you can do:

1. Relaunch expo on your phone
2. check that the phone and computer are in the same network
3. add `--tunnel` for launching the app

> expo start --tunnel

4. Restart all devices
5. Close the firewall

Answer (score 0):

The pretty simple way to solve this issue is to Turn on Airplane mode on your PC and Turn it off back, the purpose is to disconnect the system from router, again run `expo start` or `npm start --reset-cache` to be on safe side. Now you are good to go. Everything will work fine.

Comment: I solve with this, but after that i got the issue again

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to uninstall Expo in the Android Simulator, then install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to me. Then I tried to connect through the test editor.
By `npm start`. The terminal will shown the QR code, It would be easy to connect without the bundler error.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the path to your project doesnt contain any non-ASCII characters, this solved the problem for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

If you have a virus program running in the background, try disabling it

Comment: This answer just proposes the solution that was already given in the several other answers.